# Abrir janela de exclusão e envio de dados para outra página com Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, porém, tenho vários registros dentro de um laço de repetição, o valor do id que consigo pegar é último da lista. Como faço pra pegar o valor do registro individualmente.

```js
function confirmacao() {
  var resposta = confirm("Realmente deseja remover esse usuário?");
  if (resposta == true) {
    var url = "teste.php?id=" + "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class='col-sm-5 text-right' style="float: right;right: auto;left: 14px;">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick="confirmacao(this)">Excluir</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```js
function confirmacao(id) {
  var resposta = confirm("Realmente deseja remover este usuário?");

  if (resposta == true) {
    var url = "teste.php?id=" + id;
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class='col-sm-5 text-right' style="float: right;right: auto;left: 14px;">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick="confirmacao('<?php print $id; ?>')">Excluir</button>
  </div>
</div>
```